# number of binary strings with equal number of 0's and 1's

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to count the number $S$ of binary strings with equal number of 0's and 1's. Since this boils down to picking $n$ out of $2n$ places where 0's can fall into, my ansatz is
$$ S = \left(\begin{matrix} 2n \\ n \end{matrix}\right) = \frac{(2n)!}{2n!} $$

Using Stirling's approximation $ n! \approx \left(\frac n e\right)^n $
this simplifies to
$$ S \approx 2^{2n-1} \left(\frac {n} e\right)^{n} $$

However, this grows *faster* than the number of *all* possible strings of length $2n$, as
$$ 2^{2n-1} \left(\frac {n} e\right)^{n} < 2^{2n}
\Longleftrightarrow 
\left(\frac {n} e\right)^{n} < 2$$
which is obviously bound.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that $\dbinom{2n}{n} = \dfrac{(2n)!}{n! \cdot n!}$, not $\dfrac{(2n)!}{2n!}$.

In addition, Stirling's approximation is that $n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^n$: you're missing a factor.

Think you can finish from here?